# Android UI view to **enter** lists of strings in a form

Tags: android

Which Android UI component allows entry of lists of strings in a form?

Example:

Activity "Recipe" allows users to post a recipe to a database server. The activity has the following 2 fields:

- Text field: Recipe "title"
- List of strings field: "ingredients"

---

Example of a submission:

title: Pizza

ingredients:

- mozzarella
- tomato sauce
- pepperoni

---

I would like for the user to be able to enter "mozzarella", to see "mozzarella" appear in the list of ingredients and to still be able to add ingredients to complete the recipe (e.g. add "tomato sauce", add "pepperoni", all as part of the form)

---

Note: the "Transcript" API sample demo looks "similar" to this... but upside down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EditText` supports multiple lines. Listen for changes using `TextWatcher` and explode each line to your `SimpleAdapter` or similar.

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewByID(R.id.editText);
String[] ingredients = editText.getText.toString().split("\n");

SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(..., ingredients, ....);
```

Comment: Does this treat each entry as a separate "entity"? Is there a sample in the API samples? I am upvoting but I am not sure this is what I am looking for?

Comment: It will if you tell it to treat each line as an entity - at least after the parsing. I'll update my answer with a sample

Comment: Daniel, don't worry about the sample. I get what you say now.. I was more looking for something like "a single text field" on top which has an associated "list" below.. you enter one item in the text field, it gets added to the "list" below, you can delete from the list below if you made a mistake, you can keep adding if you like..

Comment: Yes, but your solution is possible too. Just use a single line EditText and a button. When the button is clicked you just append the new ingredient to the specified `ListView`. Add a touch listener on your list items to remove/edit.

Comment: Right, probably what I am looking for is that combo then.. how can I delete from a ListView? Listen for a prolonged touch event and pop up a contextual menu? Is there "iOS-like swipe to delete" on Android's ListView? I'll award the answer for this..

Comment: Yes, but these are other questions. Search SO for `onLongClick`, `Gestures` and `OptionsMenu`.